# Sending large chunks of data over WCF service

Tags: wcf

```
[DataContract]
public class Request
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public Response ProcessData(Request request)
{
    //do something with request.Data
}
```

on the client

```
string data = [some large data];
server.ProcessData(new Request() {ID=1, Data=data});
```

It works well if I pass a smaller string. But when I read a text file and pass the content of it it throws an error 'Bad Request 400'.

Update:
It works now. The following entry in the web.config on the wcf server did the trick.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Did you already try increasing `maxReceivedMessageSize`, etc. in your service configuration?

Comment: Yes I did, maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000".
I am suspecting the data, I'm passing csv text (see below). Could that be the issue?

"REVIEW_DATE","AUTHOR","ISBN","DISCOUNTED_PRICE"
"1985/01/21","Douglas Adams",0345391802,5.95

Comment: It looks like the maximum size it can take is around 8000 bytes. I added another method ProcessData1(string request) with a string parameter. It behaves the same, when the request size is more than 8000 or so it fails. The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.